# How do I level up my pros?

Tags: fifa-15

I know everyone's crazy about FUT, but me and my friends just like to play together on the same team (online) and face other players. It looks like the only way to do this in FIFA 15 is through Pro Clubs, so I had a few questions about this game mode:

1. How do we improve our "Pros", it seems we level up so slowly?
2. How do we improve our team (the non-playable players)? They're really poor on the ball and I'd since I play as ANY, I'd like for them to improve.
3. Is there any other game mode hidden away in FIFA 15, that will allow us to play online together (say, as Arsenal) vs other people online?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many achievements to be earnt by your pros that reward them with extra stats such as scoring a certain amount of headed goals may would boost their heading ability, you should be able to view these achievements and their progress on your pros stat page.

As for improving the other players stats, this is not possible, however it would be a good idea for one of you to play as 'any' which allows the one person to control the whole team as well as their pro playing in their favored position.

Finally, there is a multiplayer online seasons mode that you can play with your friend which is basically the same as the single player online seasons but you have to play with a friend.

Hope i Helped :)

Comment: That's Co-Op Seasons, but can you play with more than one friend though? There's 3 of us that want to play on the same team.

Comment: AFAIK it is only for two people, so if you want three people playing, play pro clubs

Answer (score 0):

What helps a lot is make the user gameplay shot speed high shopkeeper low and Sprint speed high pass error low etc. Do that for a season or two and that will improve your pro